# stay on activity when press back key

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, back

I have two layout (layout1,layout2) While these defined in one Activity

I used setContentView(R.layout.layout1) and setContentView(R.layout.layout2) in one Activity.

I want when clicked back, stay on the Activity and back from **layout2** to the **layout1** just.

```
public class Anatomy1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);    //*****************

        LinearLayout num1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.num1);
        num1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                setContentView(R.layout.layout2);        //*****************
                final FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_frame);
                final TouchImage iv = new TouchImage(getApplicationContext());
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.theImage);
                layout.addView(iv);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You're codes is very good, but I am a problem.

In the first stage, the amount equal to the "**null**", there is no problem, but the next time that stage is not "**null**" I have an error, perhaps because I create FrameLayout agane. What do I do to fix this problem?

[image: ![enter image description here]

this is my error:

[image: ![enter image description here]

**UPDATE**

**Finally, correct, bug of code was here:**

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried overriding `onBackPressed` and putting no codes inside that even excluding `super.onBackPressed()` like here

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 //No codes at all
}
```

**UPDATE :**

As your requirement I've tried doing and simply your `Activity` looks like this,
It sets `layout2` in default

```
boolean isLayout2 = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            if (getIntent().getStringExtra("layout").equalsIgnoreCase("layout2")) {

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                isLayout2 = false;

            }
        }
        else{
            isLayout2 = true;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        }



 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(isLayout2){

            backToLayout1();
        }
        else{
          super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }


  private void backToLayout1() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("layout","layout2");
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Hope you will understand and edit as per your need.

Comment: I want After show the image(in the layout2), when I click back, go back to the layout1.Your code does that?

Comment: you mean just to change the content but not the activity >? Why don't you take KeyCode

Comment: I have a listView in layout1 and just one FrameLayout in layout2, I want when press back, going from layout2 to layout1 and if press again go back another Activity.

Comment: As your requirements changing the setContentView only won't work for entire layout. I suggest you to reload the activity when pressing the back button when you are in layout2..

Comment: yes, reload the Activity, but I don't want this. I want when press back, going to the layout1 ,if again back going to Previous Activity.

Comment: @gadolf I've updated my answer. You can follow the pattern. I've tested these codes and working fine. Have a look. If you got any confusion then you can ask..

Comment: I do not know what I have to replace "layout" and "layout2"

Comment: At first it loads `R.layout.activity_main2` then in onBackpressed it loads `R.layout.activity_main`

Comment: I hope you fixed that bug yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed() in the activity and check for a viewId which is unique to layout2

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()